# Add JSTL to Eclipse dynamic web project with pom.xml how?

Tags: eclipse, maven, jsp, jstl

I have a dynamic web project in Eclipse with the following dependencies in its `pom.xml`:

```
javax.servlet.api: 3.1.0
postgresql: RELEASE
gson: RELEASE
```

I would like employ JSTL (core) for the project's JSPs. Currently they won't compile because of this error message:

> Cannot find the tag library descriptor for "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"

Outside the JSPs, everything compiles and runs fine. For example, my `error500.jsp` starts like this:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8" isErrorPage="true"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

What specific dependencies (suitable versions) do I have to add to `pom.xml` to overcome this problem?

Comment: I don't know the 100%-true answer, but in potlets(not servlets but portlets) you should add jstl-staff in portlet-properties.xml. May be you should do the same - just to mention that libraries in some .xml file?

Comment: Despite the claims for it to be outdated (the "newer" ones only provide the "API"), isn't https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl/1.2 what you're looking for?